# Real multiple files in Perl Thread

Tags: perl

I needed to read and do some manipulations with the so many files list in an array. The read concepts are written in the sub routine and the files are passing as an argument. The below code is read one file at time and the program takes more times while read the listed files in array.

**I would like to read_files subroutine should perform multiple times for different files.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
opendir DIRS,"/tmp";
my @files=readdir DIRS;
closedir DIRS;

foreach my $file_read(@files){
&read_files($file_read);
}

 sub read_files{
  my $R_file=shift;
  open(INP,"<$R_file");
  my $con=<INP>;
  #some manipulation will go here
  close INP;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is that simple (and I'm assuming you don't print to STDOUT in your subroutine):

```
use threads;

# create the threads
my @threads = map {threads->create(\&read_files,$_)} @files;

# wait until the threads have finished
foreach my $thread (@threads){
  $thread->join();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `fork`, it is easiest used with the [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager)

And you should take a look at [the documentation for threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and maybe the [threads tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html)

A little side note: it is much better to use the three argument open. Especially if you `open` with interpolation.